# Windows 11 starts by itself

Tags: windows, windows-11, dell-latitude, windows-11-upgrade

I'm using Windows 11 and I have this very weird issue:

Every day at at certain time my laptop just starts by itself. Exactly. It is off(not hibernated or in sleep mode) and it starts by itself. That's not cool.

Any ideas how to fix? Is it some sort of settings or is it a bug?

Comment: Can you provide the exact model of the laptop and build info for Windows.  Are there any events in the logs at that time?  Is it on a network with other devices you do not manage? Is Wake on LAN enabled?

Comment: Can you check `powercfg /waketimers` and `powercfg /requests`?

Comment: @Dave OS Build: 22000.593 and Laptop model: Dell Latitude 5521

Comment: @user1686 I entered you commands in powershell in adminstration mode. 
/waketimers: "There are no active wake timers in the system" and /requests: all set to none

Comment: Rin the Task Scheduler and check in the Task Status pane if some task has run at that hour.

Comment: If it is *truly* off, "not hibernated or in sleep mode," I don't see how it can restart on its own.  Try `shutdown /s /f /t 0` next time you shut down to do a complete job. If that still starts up on its own later, try *holding down the power key for 5 or 10 seconds (shutting down forcefully this way may cause issues if files are being written to disk, though).